# Android отключить полноэкранный режим

Tags: android

Добрый день!

Столкнулись с такой проблемой, приложение работает в полноэкранном режиме, при этом требуется постоянный вертикальный режим.

С мобильными приложениями все хорошо, да и с планшетами в целом все нормально было, пока не установили на плaншет HUAWEI с оболочкой EUMI.

Планшет сам, автоматом переходит в горизонтальный режим, если приложение переходит в полноэкранный режим, но нам этого не надо.

Мы уже отключили в настройках "Автоповорот", в приложении так же установлен только один режим, но планшет все равно автоматом переходит в горизонтальный режим. Есть ли возможность это отключить?

UPD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stylе name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></stylе>
```

UPD:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".main_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: покажите манифест

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Activity установи android:screenOrientation="portrait", надеюсь поможет

Пример:

```html
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.BottomBarActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для нормальной поддержки полноэкранного режима рекомендуется ввести такой тег в манифест:

```
<application ...>
   <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
</application>
```

Попробуйте такой вариант.

[Первоисточник](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html?m=1)